# EntityAspect property still not avail after adding an expand clause to a BreezeJS query

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, entity-framework-6, breeze

This is a follow up to the question that Ziad asked on 13 Nov 2013.  His question was in regard the EntityAspect property was no longer available after adding an expand clause in BreezeJS.  It appeared that this functionality worked in V1.4.3, but after upgrading to V1.4.5 with EF6 and WebApi2, this functionality was no longer available.  We now have a Breeze Client of V1.5, EF 6.1.1 and WebApi 2.2 and the functionality still has not been restored.  My questions are: Will this functionality ever be restored and, if not, is there a workaround available.   Unless I can find a way to overcome this issue, I have a major Breeze, Knockout, Durandal based application that is effectively dead in the water.

I have stolen Ziad example code.  I hope he does not mind because it clearly illustrates the problem. 
This code works fine:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Products").take(1);
```

The EntityAspect property for the row is available.

However, when he added an expand clause:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Products").expand("Orders").take(1);
```

Here is the code Ziad used to retrieve the data:

```
var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager(rootUrl + 'breeze/ProductsApi');
mgr.executeQuery(query, function (data) {
alert(data.results[0].entityAspect); // undefined.
});
```

The EntityAspect property for the row was now undefined and the fields retrieved showed up as plain values instead of  KnockoutJS type observables.

I was able to get around the issues of the retrieved fields showing up as plain text.  I believe it was because I used ko.observableArray instead of ko.observable.  But the problem with EntityAspect not working on expand structures is a showstopper.  I cannot keep my UI and my underlying Breeze cache synchronized.  My SaveChanges functionality does seem to work reliably.  Trying to make this work has only produced hours of frustration.

I am about to either walk away from this Breeze/Knockout project or return to a version of the project that used Durandal, Odata, and Knockout.  The project worked when I used Odata.   The overhead needed to save a structure was complex, but it worked.   Without the ability to use EntityAspect throughout an expanded structure,  using Breeze/Knockout appears to be an unusable option.

What is interesting to note is that I am using Visual Studio 2013.  The Intellisense with VS 2013 indicates that EntityAspect functionality is available.  However, when I run the application, the functionality is simply not there.

If someone can help me solve this problem, I would greatly appreciate the help and three weeks of total frustration would finally come to an end.

Unfortunately Ziad receive no answers when he raised the question last in November 2013.  Hopefully I will have been luck.  I cannot believe that this problem with EntityAspect is not affecting a large number of users in the Breeze/Knockout programming community.

Comment: We did check with Breeze version 1.4.11 and entityaspect works even  when we do use EXPAND inside the Query.  Now, I can confirm that the very same query in version 1.5.0 does not return the enttyAspect at all when EXPAND is specified.

Comment: Did you add a [queryable] attribute to your controller or to a controller method such as `Products`?

Comment: Hi,  We did try [EnableQuery] on Metadata() and we did make sure that the metadata was OK. Now, we did not get back any entityAspect when using the Query Expand feature... One more time we do not have the issue when using  Breeze 1.4.11!  could you please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [Breeze Web API documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller), you **cannot use the Web API `[EnableQuery]` or `[Queryable]`** attributes in your controllers.

The`[EnableQuery]`/`[Queryable]` attributes change the Json.net serialization configuration such that a Breeze client cannot recognize the types of the included entities. Consequently, it treats the JSON data in the expanded nodes as Plain Old JavaScript Objects, not as entities with an `entityAspect` property.

The `[BreezeQueryable]` attribute preserves the essential serialization configuration.

**Apply `[BreezeQueryable]` instead to your Web API controller query method.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by upgrading the Breeze Client - Javascript, Breeze Client and Server - Javascript client with ASP.NET and Entity Framework 6, Breeze Server - ContextProvider for Entity Framework 6, Breeze Server - ContextProvider, and Breeze Server - for Web API 2.2 software packages to Version 1.5.1.

Thank you to everyone who worked on the code changes required to fix this problem.

Also when you upgrade to to Breeze Version 1.5.1, you need to use the attribute [EnableBreezeQuery], instead of the attrbutes [EnableQuery],  [BreezeQueryable], or [Queryable] attributes that were used in older versions.

So if you upgrade to Breeze 1.5.1 to fix the EXPAND issue,
**Apply [EnableBreezeQuery] to your Web API controller query method.**